# Lenovo Ideapad U430p audio, drivers

Tags: 14.04, sound, lenovo, ideapad

I have just ordered lenovo U430p, Installed ubuntu 14.04. Everything worked like a charm, except the audio. 
Though audio works and is detected by the system, the sound is very low as compared to windows 8.1(comes preinstalled).

```
rahul@rahul-IdeaPad-U430p:~$ uname -a
Linux rahul-IdeaPad-U430p 3.13.0-30-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 9 22:45:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

rahul@rahul-IdeaPad-U430p:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
rahul@rahul-IdeaPad-U430p:~$ 


rahul@rahul-IdeaPad-U430p:~$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 66
    Memory at b2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 64
    Memory at b2610000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 61
    Memory at b2600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 67
    Memory at b2618000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 68
    Memory at b2614000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: b2500000-b25fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: b2400000-b24fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: b1000000-b1ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000b0000000-00000000b0ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at b261c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 62
    I/O ports at 5088 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 5094 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 5080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 5090 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 5060 [size=32]
    Memory at b261b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: medium devsel
    Memory at b2619000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 5040 [size=32]

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 0123
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 63
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Memory at b2504000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at b2500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 65
    Memory at b2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your main sound is the second one (first one is hdmi sound) so install "Pulse audio volume control" from software center (or `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`), launch it from multimedia menu.
- Go in "output devices" tab and set volume for the last device.
- Changing profile in last right tab can help to.
- You can also set volume lauching `alsamixer` in a terminal, then press F6 to select the 2nd card, right/left arrows to select fader , up/down arrows to set volume, m key to unmute/mute.

Comment: Thanks , for the quick response
I tried both the options, no difference in the sound.
I guess I have to live with a little less sound......